# Laravel PHPUnit Testing with Internal Http Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, dingo-api

I am new to laravel and I am trying to build a PHPUnit testing using `phpunit` command. However, the test keeps saying `Expected status code 200 but received 400`. And when I test same uri on Postman, it works perfectly fine.

When I use `phpunit` command, `request()->segment(1)` would return `null`. However, making requests with Postman would return correct value for `request()->segment(1)` which is 'api'.

I am using dingo package for api request.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Edited: I've found the problem which was that when I run command line like `phpunit`, `request()` would recognize the command as request. So, how could I go around?

Here is my test code

**ClientTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Client;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ClientTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/api/v1/clients/1');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

}
```

And here is my api route code

**route/api.php**

```
<?php

use Dingo\Api\Routing\Router;

if ( request()->segment(1) === 'api' ) {
    $apiRouter = app(Router::class);
    $apiVersion = strtolower(request()->segment(2));

    $apiRouter->version($apiVersion, function ($apiRouter) use ($apiVersion)
    {
        $pathPrefix = 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1';

        $apiRouter->get($apiVersion.'/clients/{id}', $pathPrefix.'\Client\ClientController@index');

    });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$this->getJson()` instead of `$this->get()` since this is about a json request. Also that pathprefix is not necessary laravel has several helpers to create routes. you are looking for the action() helper in this case

Comment: @Christophvh I've just tried `this->getJson()` but with no luck.